# Jotai with page refresh in next.js

Tags: cookies, next.js, page-refresh, session-storage, jotai

How does one let server know the values of jotai store so it can give back the same values when the user refreshes the page?

Do I have to maintain a copy of Jotai store in session store or a cookie?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.